# Setting up tabs to pull content from a html file, can't get it right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/869365am/

I am not very familiar with js, which is my main problem I realize.

I am trying to set up tabs for different restaurant menus and I've decided (I don't know why, right now I am considering throwing in my towel and doing it the normal way) to have the tabs pull the content from another html page. But it's not working. It just takes you to that html page instead of showing the content within the tabbed space.

```
    <section id="menu">
  <div class="container menu_wrap">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
      <div class="span10 offset1">
        <section class="menu_options"> 
          <a class="menu_btn" href="dine-in.html">Dine in</a> 
          <a class="menu_btn" href="take-away.html">Take Away</a>
          <a class="menu_btn" href="lunch-menu.html">Lunch</a> 
        </section>
        <div class="menu_border">
          <div class="menu_inner">
            <h2 class="choose">CHOOSE A MENU!</h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <section class="container white_divide"></section>



</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different strategy. I would store your menu html in the same page in hidden divs that would be displayed when buttons are clicked.

You can see a demo from your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/869365am/1/

```
<section id="menu">
  <div class="container menu_wrap">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
      <div class="span10 offset1">
        <section class="menu_options"> 
          <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('dine-in');">Dine in</button> 
          <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('take-away');">Take Away</button>
          <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('lunch');">Lunch</button> 
        </section>
        <div class="menu_border">
          <div class="menu_inner">
            <h2 class="choose">CHOOSE A MENU!</h2>
              <div id="dine-in" style="display:none">Dine Menu HTML HERE</div>
              <div id="take-away" style="display:none">Take Away Menu HTML HERE</div>
              <div id="lunch" style="display:none">Lunch Menu HTML HERE</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <section class="container white_divide"></section>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
displayMenu = function(menu){
    $(".menu_inner").find(".menu-active").toggleClass("menu-active").slideToggle();
    $(".menu_inner").find("#"+menu).toggleClass("menu-active").slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Not how I was wanting to do it, but it does work as a workaround.

Comment: You are welcome. The way you were trying is not the correct. You cant include content from other html files unless you are using Iframes or a load() function as explained by benjarwar. Using hidden divs is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing quite a few things that are going wrong here. Some basics, first:

1. The JSFiddle doesn't include jQuery as an external library. So, in your demo, all that will happen is the links will fire normally, going straight to the target document specified in their href attributes.
2. When using jQuery, it's best to wrap your code in a [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler to ensure the library is loaded.
3. It looks like you're trying to do some additional stuff, like fading the content in and out. I'd try to simplify and get the content to load first
4. If you're not running your code on a local server (like you're just dropping the HTML file into a browser), you might be running into cross-domain issues.

Some specifics:

1. I'd avoid putting your handler functions (e.g. loadContent) inside of the click handler. It's better to declare them before hand.
2. You're referencing a #load element that doesn't appear in your markup. Let's get rid of that stuff while debugging.
3. It looks like you're referencing .menu_inner as part of the target document to load. That will search for .menu_inner elements in the *target* file, such as dine-in.html. I don't think that's what you want to do; I believe you're trying to load the contents of dine-in.html (et al) into the current page's .menu_inner element.

Putting it all together and simplifying, this is really all you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_options a').click(function(){  
        $('.menu_inner').load($(this).attr('href'));  
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've forked your JSFiddle, but note this isn't going to work there because the target documents are 404 (keep your browser's JS console open to see errors).

http://jsfiddle.net/3f0y0r73/1/

Once you've got this basic step working, then you can start fancying it up with fadeIn and fadeOut stuff!

Comment: Hmmm... I tried this, and I agree that I need to go simple first, but when the tab is clicked, it opens up the page instead of showing the page in the tab area. Here it is live, since it is hard to describe http://daleamann.com/tabtest/test.html

Comment: Are you certain that jQuery is loaded? Have you looked in your browser's console for errors? It sounds like the link is still firing normally.

Comment: Looking at that live example, the only function I can see that binds click events to your tabs is in http://daleamann.com/tabtest/assets/js/main.js:9-14. The handler doesn't return false or prevent the default link functionality. So the link is still firing normally.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make it work how I want to... until I figure it out, I'm just going to use @Below the Radar's suggestion.